# How do I know if today is a day due to change civil local time e.g. daylight saving time in standard python and pandas timestamps?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timezone, timezone-offset

According to the rules of British Summer Time / daylight saving time (https://www.gov.uk/when-do-the-clocks-change) the clocks:

- go forward 1 hour at 1am on the last Sunday in March,
- go back 1 hour at 2am on the last Sunday in October.

In 2019 this civil local time change happens on March 31st and October 27th, but **the days slightly change every year**. Is there a clean way to know these dates for each input year?

I need to check these "changing time" dates in an automatic way, is there a way to avoid a for loop to check the details of each date to see if it is a "changing time" date?

At the moment I am exploring these dates for 2019 just to try to figure out a reproducible/automatic procedure and I found this:

```
# using datetime from the standard library
march_utc_30 = datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
march_utc_31 = datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
april_utc_1 = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
# using pandas timestamps
pd_march_utc_30 = pd.Timestamp(march_utc_30) #, tz='UTC')
pd_march_utc_31 = pd.Timestamp(march_utc_31) #, tz='UTC')
pd_april_utc_1 = pd.Timestamp(april_utc_1) #, tz='UTC')
# using pandas wrappers
pd_local_march_utc_30 = pd_march_utc_30.tz_convert('Europe/London')
pd_local_march_utc_31 = pd_march_utc_31.tz_convert('Europe/London')
pd_local_april_utc_1 = pd_april_utc_1.tz_convert('Europe/London')
# then printing all these dates
print("march_utc_30 {} pd_march_utc_30 {} pd_local_march_utc_30 {}".format(march_utc_30, pd_march_utc_30, pd_local_march_utc_30))
print("march_utc_31 {} pd_march_utc_31 {} pd_local_march_utc_31 {}".format(march_utc_31, pd_march_utc_31, pd_local_march_utc_31))
print("april_utc_1  {} pd_april_utc_1  {} pd_local_april_utc_1  {}".format(april_utc_1, pd_april_utc_1, pd_local_april_utc_1))
```

The output of those `print` statements is:

```
march_utc_30 2019-03-30 00:00:00+00:00 pd_march_utc_30 2019-03-30 00:00:00+00:00 pd_local_march_utc_30 2019-03-30 00:00:00+00:00
march_utc_31 2019-03-31 00:00:00+00:00 pd_march_utc_31 2019-03-31 00:00:00+00:00 pd_local_march_utc_31 2019-03-31 00:00:00+00:00
april_utc_1  2019-04-01 00:00:00+00:00 pd_april_utc_1  2019-04-01 00:00:00+00:00 pd_local_april_utc_1  2019-04-01 01:00:00+01:00
```

I could use a `for` loop to **find out if the current date is the last Sunday of the month**, or compare the "hour delta" between the current date and the date of the day after to see if there is a +1, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

Is there something attached to the year e.g. knowing the input year is `2019` then we know for sure the "change date" in March will be day 31st?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`dateutil.rrule`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) can help (install with `pip install python-dateutil`).

Because we can fetch dates by weeks, we don't need any loops,

```
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, WEEKLY
from dateutil.rrule import SU as Sunday
from datetime import date
import datetime

def get_last_sunday(year, month):
    date = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=1)
    # we can find max 5 sundays in a months
    days = rrule(freq=WEEKLY, dtstart=date, byweekday=Sunday, count=5)
    # Check if last date is same month,
    # If not this couple year/month only have 4 Sundays
    if days[-1].month == month:
        return days[-1]
    else:
        return days[-2]

def get_march_switch(year):
    # Get 5 next Sundays from first March
    day = get_last_sunday(year, 3)
    return day.replace(hour=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

def get_october_switch(year):
    day = get_last_sunday(year, 10)
    return day.replace(hour=2, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

print('2019:')
print('  {}'.format(get_march_switch(2019)))
print('  {}'.format(get_october_switch(2019)))

print('2021:')
print('  {}'.format(get_march_switch(2021)))
print('  {}'.format(get_october_switch(2021)))
```

`get_sundays()` returns the 5 next sundays from the first day of the given `month`, because a month can have maximum 5 sundays.

Then I just check (within `get_(march|october)_switch()`) if the last given sunday is from the expected month, if not well this month only have 4 sunday, I took this one.

Finally I fix the hours, seconds and microseconds.

Output:

```
2019:
  2019-03-31 01:00:00
  2019-10-27 02:00:00
2021:
  2021-03-28 01:00:00
  2021-10-24 02:00:00
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning we are returning "timezone-less" datetimes. That "hour offset" needs to be carefully interpreted (is it UTC based or is it BST based on timezone `Europe/London`)

Answer (score 1):

I know the topic is quite old now. However, I had the same question today, and at the end I found a solution which seems quite simple to me, using only the standard datetime:

I want to check whether my date *refdate* is the October DST day - I did it in the following way:

*refdate* is my standard datetime object.
If you have a panda timestamp, you can convert it to native datetime using `.to_pydatetime()`

```py
if refdate.month == 10 and refdate.weekday() == 6 and (refdate + dt.timedelta(weeks = 1)).month == 11:
    oct_dst = 1
```

Comment: I thought so too, but depending on the actual date and the time zone this might be wrong. Transition days change sometimes. I found this blog post explaining it further. https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2019/03/21/coding-time-zones-and-daylight-saving-time/